# Why is setting a derefernce pointer equal to a primitive illegal?

Tags: c, pointers

Why does setting the value of a dereferenced pointer raise a Segmentation fault 11? To make what I mean clear look a the follow code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *ptr;
*ptr = 2;

int main(){
  printf("%d\n", *ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

I thought that *ptr=2 would set the rvalue that the pointer ptr is point to to 2. Is that not the case? I apologize if for those c expert programmers, this is really easy/obvious.

Are we only allowed to set a dereferenced pointer (i.e. *ptr) to a value if that value had a memory address? i.e. like doing:

```
int k = 7;
int *ptr = k;
```

and then:

```
*ptr = 2;
```

Comment: In your first example, ptr isn't allocated.

Comment: `*ptr = 2;` is an assignment statement. It belongs in a function body.

Comment: @A Person It only gives a warning in gcc. (For me.) The code will compile. Not to say it's correct code.

Comment: You're dereferencing a null pointer as if it points to something.

Comment: I should go back to the text book and re-read the chapter on pointers. 1. `ptr` You have not allocated any memory for it to point to 2) `int *ptr = &k` is what you are looking for. 3) Why is this tagged C++ when using `printf`

Comment: @remyabel It's likely undefined behaviour if it compiles. If not, it should be treated as such, no questions asked.

Comment: @remyabel - It is a good idea to turn on all warnings

Comment: @Ed Heal I'm pointing out that OP wouldn't have run into a compiler error unless he was invocating C++ mode. Chances are he doesn't have warnings on.

Comment: Honestly, the best answer you can get out of this is to read a book. This is covered in every C language learning book in existence, and Stack Overflow isn't a tutorial on things that have that property.

Comment: @remyabel, [Clang agrees for C as well.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37c0ed458d486979)

Comment: I moved *ptr = 2; inside the function body and it still crashed :(

Comment: @Pinocchio, Yes, because null pointers (because it's global, it's initialized to 0) don't point to anything, so trying to use what it points to isn't going to work.

Comment: Please see this [meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158450/retagging-c-questions-as-c-without-consulting-asker) before changing the tags without asking the OP.

Comment: @chris With pedantic-errors, yes.

Comment: You have both C and C++ tags which compiler are you using and let's stick to one tag unless you are concerned about the difference between C and C++.

Comment: @remyabel, From my experiences, `-pedantic-errors` pretty much just kills things that some compilers let through that aren't standard anyway.

Comment: The root problem is just like what @remyabel say: allocated space for it first!

Comment: @remyabel, After actually reading the errors more carefully, I have a new theory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151653/why-is-setting-a-derefernce-pointer-equal-to-a-primitive-illegal/21151769?noredirect=1#comment31836957_21151739

Comment: I strongly believe the OP is using C due to the code compiling in the first place. C++ simply won't, while C does it in a rather sneaky way. Therefore, I'm taking the C++ tag off again.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `ptr` is not pointing to allocated space. See the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void){

  // Create a pointer to an integer.
  // This pointer will point to some random (likely unallocated) memory address.
  // Trying set the value at this memory address will almost certainly cause a segfault.
  int *ptr;

  // Create a new integer on the heap, and assign its address to ptr.
  // Don't forget to call free() on it later!
  ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr)); 

  // Alternatively, we could create a new integer on the stack, and have
  // ptr point to this.
  int value;
  ptr = &value;

  // Set the value of our new integer to 2.
  *ptr = 2;

  // Print out the value at our now properly set integer.
  printf("%d\n", *ptr);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to do this to you, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151653/why-is-setting-a-derefernce-pointer-equal-to-a-primitive-illegal/21151769?noredirect=1#comment31837123_21151653. I hope the edit makes up for it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not 'illegal', it's simply implementation defined. In fact, on some platforms (such as DOS), specific memory addresses were necessary, for example to write text to the video buffer which started at 0xB8000, or memory mapped controller I/O on the SNES.

On most current OS's, a feature called [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is used, for security reasons, which makes ancient modes of dedicated addresses a thing of the past, in favor of going through driver and kernel layers, which is what makes it 'illegal' for most places you would run it.

Comment: It's maybe worth adding that fixed memory addresses and memory mapping etc. are still widely used in areas such as embedded systems programming (i.e. where there is no OS).

Comment: Well, the C99 standard labels it as "invalid" in §6.5.3.3: *Among the invalid values for dereferencing a pointer by the unary * operator are a null pointer...*. Invalid shouldn't mean implementation-defined.

Comment: @chris as far as I know this is simply plain old undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Richard, After more pondering, I'm getting more sure that I finally understand what the `*ptr = 2;` is actually doing and how your answer makes much more sense with that. A note on what the OP's program actually *does* would be a great addition.

Comment: @chris OK guys, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21152378/1508519) for a question I just posted. Hopefully it can clear up the confusion. TL;DR it is not undefined behavior, `*ptr` is treated as a redeclaration, therefore it's equivalent to `int* ptr = 2`, not `*ptr = 2`.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic issue here is that you are not assigning `ptr` to a valid memory address, there are some cases where `0` is a valid memory address but usually not. Since `ptr` is *global variable* in your first case, it will be initialized to `0`. remyabal asked a great follow-up question and [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21152378/1708801) made me realize that this is a redeclaration here:

```
*ptr = 2;
```

and you are then setting `ptr` to have a value of `2` which is except by chance unlikely to point to a valid memory address.

If `ptr` was a local or *automatic variable* then it would be uninitialized and it's value would be indeterminate. Using a pointer with an indeterminate value is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in both C and C++. It is in most case undefined behavior to use a `NULL` pointer as well although implementations are allowed to define the behavior.

On most modern system attempting to access memory your process does not own will result in a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

You can assign a valid memory address to `ptr` in a few ways, for example:

```
int k = 7;
int *ptr = &k;
           ^
```

note the use of of `&` to take the address of `k` or you could use [malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) to allocate memory dynamically for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid, though some C compilers may permit it for compatibility with older versions of the language.

Statements, including assignment statements, are illegal (a syntax error) if they appear outside the body of a function.

You have:

```
int *ptr;
*ptr = 2;
```

at file scope. The first line is a valid declaration of an `int*` object called `ptr`, implicitly initialized to a null pointer value. The second line *looks* like an assignment statement, but since it's outside a function, the compiler most likely won't even try to interpret it that way. gcc treats it as a *declaration*. Old versions of C permitted you to omit the type name in a declaration; C99 dropped the "implicit `int`" rule. So gcc treats

```
*ptr = 2;
```

as equivalent to

```
int *ptr = 2;
```

and produces the following warnings:

```
c.c:4:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
c.c:4:8: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

The first warning is because you omitted the `int` (or other type name) from the declaration. The second is because `2` is a value of type `int`, and you're using it to initialize an object of type `int*`; there is no implicit conversion from `int` to `int*` (other than the special case of a null pointer constant).

Once you get past that, you have two declarations of the same object -- but they're compatible, so that's permitted. And the pointer variable is initialized to `(int*)2`, which is a garbage pointer value (there's not likely to be anything useful at memory address `0x00000002`).

In your `main` function, you do:

```
printf("%d\n", *ptr);
```

which attempts to print the value of an `int` object at that memory address. Since that address is not likely to be one that your program has permission to access, a segmentation fault is not a surprising result. (More generally, the behavior is undefined.)

(This is a fairly common problem in C: minor errors in a program can result in something that still compiles, but is completely different from what you intended. The way I think of it is that C's grammar is relatively"dense"; small random tweaks to a valid program often produce different but syntactically valid programs rather than creating syntax errors.)

So that's what your program actually does; I'm sure it's not what you intended it to do.

Take a deep breath and read on.

---

Here's something that's probably closer to what you intended:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *ptr;

int main(void) {
    *ptr = 2;
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Since there's now no initializer for `ptr`, it's implicitly initialized to a null pointer value. (And if `ptr` were defined inside `main`, its initial value would be garbage.) The assignment statement attempts to dereference that null pointer, causing a segmentation fault (again, the behavior is undefined; a segmentation fault is a likely result). Execution never reaches the `printf` call.

> I thought that `*ptr=2` would set the rvalue that the pointer `ptr` is point to to 2. Is that not the case?

Not quite. Pointers don't point to rvalues; an "rvalue" is merely the value of an expression. Pointers point to *objects* (if they point to anything). The assignment

```
*ptr = 2;
```

*would* assign the value `2` to the object that `ptr` points to -- but `ptr` doesn't point to an object!

Now let's see a version of your program that actually works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int *ptr;
int variable;

int main(void) {
    ptr = &variable;
    *ptr = 2;
    printf("*ptr     = %d\n", *ptr);
    printf("variable = %d\n", variable);
    return 0;
}
```

Now `ptr` points to an object, and `*ptr = 2` assigns a value to that object. The output is:

```
*ptr     = 2
variable = 2
```