# Redefinition of a pointer in global scope

Tags: c

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151653/why-is-setting-a-derefernce-pointer-equal-to-a-primitive-illegal) I am thoroughly confused about this seemingly basic aspect of C. Consider these two lines of code:

```
int *ptr;
*ptr = 2;
```

gcc will emit the following warnings:

```
main.cpp:4:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]

 *ptr = 2;
 ^
main.cpp:4:2: warning: type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'ptr' [enabled by default]

 *ptr = 2;
  ^
main.cpp:4:8: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

 *ptr = 2;
        ^
```

What type is `ptr` being defaulted to, `int` or `int*` (as in, is `ptr` a pointer, or an `int`)? If so, does this mean that `ptr` is pointing to address 2, or is that unchanged? I would assume that it's changed because it crashes unless you give `ptr` a valid address.

```
int i = 5;
int *ptr;
*ptr = &i;

int main(){
    printf("%d", *ptr); // 5
}
```

I am aware of the possibility of undefined behavior and that you shouldn't ignore warnings, but I'm trying to see what actually happens here.

For context, see the comment chain under this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21151739/1508519).

Comment: The subsequent errors might be caused by previous ones. Just allocate memory for the pointer or point it to valid memory.

Comment: When the compiler finds a problem it tries its best to figure out what is best to do. With warnings applied this throws up a warning and it carries on the best it can. This may cause subsequent warnings. Best to focus on the first warning and correct that first

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is what's going on: since the two lines that you are showing are in the file scope (as opposed to a local scope) both lines are treated as *declarations*, not as a declaration and an assignment statement. This is because there could be no statements at the file scope - only declarations and definitions are allowed.

Old C rules allowed declarations of type `int` to omit type altogether. Therefore, the second line is

- A declaration / definition of `ptr`
- ...which is a pointer, because it has an asterisk
- ...and it is also a pointer to `int`, because the type is missing.

That last rule is very archaic, and it has been deprecated in the ANSI version of the language standard. That is why you get a warning. If you change your code to

```
int *ptr;
int *ptr = &i;
```

your code is going to compile and run ([demo](http://ideone.com/LX44HU)).

Now one question remains: how come the compiler does not complain about duplicate declarations? It turns out that the compiler will treat multiple identical declarations as one and the same, as long as they are entirely identical to each other.

Comment: Is the code undefined behavior even though it works for those reasons?

Comment: I believe "undefined behavior" means "the language spec does not tell how a compiler should behave" and "it works" means "the compiler that you used made a choice that did what you want."

Comment: @remyabel It does not have undefined behavior. The standard honors the old rule about declarations without an explicit type being considered `int` implicitly, so it has the same meaning as `int *ptr=&i;`

Comment: Can someone explain for me? It just look like using uninitialized pointer(and unallocated) and so cause segmentfault for me, it's special because it's in global area?

Comment: @moeCake The second declaration (i.e. `*ptr = &i`) provides a valid initialization. The fact that `int` is implied makes it harder to read, but it's actually the same as `int *ptr = &i`. It is *not* a dereference of an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight So the whole point is in file scope, i.e. `*ptr = 2` in fact work like `int *ptr = 2` and is deprecated ? So anyway don't do thing like that.