# C - error on reclaring variable

Tags: c, ch

I'm using the [Ch C compiler/environment](http://www.softintegration.com/products/chstandard/) to learn C. I note that when I want to redeclare variables with the same name I get an error:

```
/Users/srm> int c = 1
/Users/srm> c++
/Users/srm> c
/Users/srm> 2
/Users/srm> int c = 3
ERROR: identifier 'c' redeclared
ERROR: invalid lvalue of assignment operation
```

Is this is a restriction imposed by Ch or a C language feature?

Comment: Just use `c = 3`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21275992/redeclaration-of-global-variable-vs-local-variable

Comment: If you want to learn C, use a C compiler. It is not clear if ch actually supports standard C or just some older version, possibly the long time outdated C90 only. And if you want to know if something is standard, get a good C book and have the standard under your pillow. C is not a language for trial&error learning.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write just `c = 3`, as far as I understand.

Comment: So this means I cannot change the data type of a variable, once declared.

Comment: You can if you use a language that allows that.

Comment: @srm If you have a nested scope (you introduce a new scope with braces), you can shadow a variable - essentially, declare a new variable with the same name, and it can have a different type. But the shadowed variable will be inaccessible until you return to the outer scope.

Comment: as @Kevin explained, it's all about variable scopes in C. Google it or visit [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Scope/Examples)

Comment: @Kevin: Shadowing any name is bad practice and should never be done intentionally.

Comment: @Olaf Definitely agreed, but shadowing is the closest thing to what the question was asking about. I'm just saying it's possible, not that it's a good thing to do.

Comment: @Kevin: It is never wrong to be very explicit about bad practice. Remember this is read mistly by beginners (experience programmers should be aware of it already).